# How to get same loadings scales for biplots produced from stats::biplot and ggplot2::autoplot from ggfortify R package?

Tags: r, graph, pca, ggfortify

The scales of loadings for biplots produced from `stats::biplot` and `ggplot2::autoplot` from `ggfortify` `R` package are different. How can I get the same loadings scales for biplots produced from `stats::biplot` and `ggplot2::autoplot` from `ggfortify` `R` package?

```
stats::biplot(prcomp(USArrests, scale = TRUE))
```

[image]

```
library(ggfortify)
ggplot2::autoplot(stats::prcomp(USArrests, scale=TRUE), label = TRUE, loadings.label = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: which one do you want? Have `stat::biplot` with equal axes or `autoplot` with different axes? The second one is probably impossible: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3101876/4132844

Comment: For `stats::biplot` the call would be `stats::biplot(prcomp(USArrests, scale = TRUE),pc.biplot=T)` , but I assume you want the autoplot version because this would be to easy for the bounty. :-)

Comment: there are a few questions about dual axes in ggplot and [some examples](http://rpubs.com/kohske/dual_axis_in_ggplot2) floating around. might be easier to make your base plot look better than adding two extra ggplot axes